# Does the peoplePickerNavigationController: shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson method not work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook

I am running the following code which utilizes Apples address book UI. The cancel method works but my shouldContinueAfterSelecting does not. I would like the word Test to be logged when I click a contact in my address book view controller. Is there another method I should be using?

```
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
    NSLog(@"Test");

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    NSLog(@"Test");
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
    NSLog(@"Test");
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This method is deprecated. Apple docs say:

Use

```
peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson:
```

or

```
peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson:property:identifier:
```